# p:fileDownload and websphere 7.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websphere

We have a file download feature using p:filedownload and it works fine on Tomcat7/Windows and Weblogic 12c and 11g /windows , but after porting our project onto Websphere 7/AIX platform, there seems to be problem while downloading small files. Once the file is less then 4096 bytes(4k), though we're able to click the download link and get the file, the file downloaded is always with a size of 0K, which is just an empty file, but it just works correctly for files larger then 4k. I'm not sure what's the root cause of this strange problem, and no exception can be found in log files. Anyone can help with this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding the needed content to the facescontext output stream by hand if the file is less than 4k –

Comment: How you did that? @user2269148